# build docker file on host with Jenkins running in container

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu, jenkins

I am trying to build a docker image using Jenkins pipeline, with Jenkins running in a Docker container.

This is my Jenkinsfile:

```
   stage 'Deploy'
         dir('/apps/npt'){
            sh 'chmod +x deploy_prod.sh'
            sh 'cat deploy_prod.sh'
            sh './deploy_prod.sh'
         }
```

this is how I start my container:

```
docker run --detach --publish 8080:8080 -u 0  --volume jenkins_volume:/var/jenkins_home  --volume apps:/apps --name jenkins jenkins/jenkins
```

This is the sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
#build docker container
docker build -t npt .
```

This is the error I get:

```
./deploy_prod.sh: line 6: docker: command not found
```

I have tried to add the docker socket as a volume to the container `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`, but stil same error.

I am using the same configuration on a different project with jenkins running as a service on the VM, with no issues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add docker client inside the Jenkins docker container. Take a look at [https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md#installing-more-tools](http://You%20will%20need%20to%20add%20docker%20client%20inside%20the%20Jenkins%20docker%20container.%20Take%20a%20look%20at%20https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md#installing-more-tools%20for%20how.) for how to do that. You can also install it within the container using docker exec.

When the script runs inside the container, it checks the PATH variable to resolve `docker` command. The docker client then writes instructions to /var/run/docker.sock. The docker server reads these instructions and acts accordingly.

`-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` -> this means that the docker client within your docker container can talk to docker engine(server/VM) running on host.